# saving file in internal storage android

Tags: android, local-storage, mkdirs

i'm new to android, and i'm having a problem when i'm trying to save a file into internal storage, the new example works on my sdk, but doesn't work on my phone.

I'm trying to run de example in a sony Ericsson xperia, with android 2.1 by the way... the log.i - gives me the next line:

```
/data/data/com.example.key/files/text/(my_title)
```

Thanks.

```
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.new_text);

            file = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.title_new);
            entry = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.entry_new);

            btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save_new);
            btn.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    File myDir = getFilesDir();


                    NEWFILENAME = file.getText().toString();
                    if (NEWFILENAME.contentEquals("")){
                        NEWFILENAME = "UNTITLED";
                    }
                    NEWENTRY = entry.getText().toString();

                    try {

                        File file_new = new File(myDir+"/text/", NEWFILENAME);
                        file_new.createNewFile();

                        Log.i("file", file_new.toString());

                        if (file_new.mkdirs()) {
                            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file_new);

                            fos.write(NEWENTRY.getBytes());
                            fos.flush();
                            fos.close();
                        }

                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    Intent textPass = new Intent("com.example.TEXTMENU");
                    startActivity(textPass);
                }
            });

            }


 //That's for creating... then in other activity i'm reading

            @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.text_menu);

            btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.newNote);
            listfinal = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

            btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent textPass = new Intent("com.example.TEXTNEW");
                    startActivity(textPass);

                }
            });

            listfinal.setOnItemClickListener(this);

            File fileWithinMyDir = getApplicationContext().getFilesDir();


            loadbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loadList);

            loadbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    File myDir = getFilesDir();

                    File dir = new File(myDir + "/text/");

                    String[] files = dir.list();

                    //String[] files = getApplicationContext().fileList();
                    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

                    for (int i =0; i < files.length; i++){
                        list.add(files[i]);
                    }
                    ArrayAdapter<String> ad = new ArrayAdapter<String>(TextMenu.this,  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                                    android.R.id.text1, list);

                    listfinal.setAdapter(ad);
                }
            });
            }
```

in my android manifiest i have the permissions

```
              <uses-sdk
                    android:minSdkVersion="5"
                    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

                <uses-permission android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Could you provide the LogCat?

Comment: Try creating the directory where you want to place your file first with `File.mkdirs()` call

Answer (score 33):

I'm not too sure which example you are referring to but I have two working samples here of which at least one of them should suit your needs.
I tested these on an X10 running Build number 2.1.A.0.435, one Xperia T running Build number 7.0.A.1.303 and one Nexus S running Build number JZO54K

Example 1

```
    String filename = "myfile";
    String outputString = "Hello world!";

    try {
        FileOutputStream outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        outputStream.write(outputString.getBytes());
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        FileInputStream inputStream = openFileInput(filename);
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
            total.append(line);
        }
        r.close();
        inputStream.close();
        Log.d("File", "File contents: " + total);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Example 2

```
    String filename = "mysecondfile";
    String outputString = "Hello world!";
    File myDir = getFilesDir();

    try {
        File secondFile = new File(myDir + "/text/", filename);
        if (secondFile.getParentFile().mkdirs()) {
            secondFile.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(secondFile);

            fos.write(outputString.getBytes());
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        File secondInputFile = new File(myDir + "/text/", filename);
        InputStream secondInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(secondInputFile));
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(secondInputStream));
        StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
            total.append(line);
        }
        r.close();
        secondInputStream.close();
        Log.d("File", "File contents: " + total);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: why is the check `secondFile.getParentFile().mkdirs()` can you please explain?

Comment: if you're still interested in an answer: this call is for making sure, that the path to the file exists, it is creating the directory hierarchy if needed

Comment: If someone still takes interest in this answer: WHen targeting API 23+, the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission has to be requested at runtime. Otherwise a "Permission denied" error will appear

Comment: @LunarWatcher That's a good point, good you brought it up. I'll update the answer, as it may help others in the future who come here.

Answer (score 1):

I had "Permission denied" issue with Samsung Galaxy S7 even though I had given read and write permissions in manifest file. I solved it by going to phone settings >> application >> [my app] and allowed "Storage" under permission. Worked fine after that.

Comment: **Pitfall:** The write external storage permission has to be requested at runtime if the app targets API 23 or higher. WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is a dangerous permission, meaning it has to be requested.