# Android: how to store (add and delete) files to an application

Tags: android, file, file-upload, download

Thank you for your time and consideration.

I am facing the following situation and I need some advice on how to proceed.

I am building an application that needs to store files (pdf, word,...) that are downloaded form the internet or come as attachments in emails, etc.

The application needs to have the ability to add and delete the files.

Please I need some suggestion hon how to proceed to implement such a functionality.

Please if there is some open source project that I could re-use for the purpose that would be very helpful as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check [Storage Options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) and [Saving Files](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html) docs of Android.

And in these links there are implementations of how to save and delete files to/from internal/external storage.

[Lars Vogel's Example](http://www.vogella.com/code/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/content/ExternalStorage.html) (there are very useful learning/sample documentations in his website. I recommend you to take a look to his website)

[Sample Read/Write Program](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1523)

[Saving to External Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7887078/android-saving-file-to-external-storage)

[Saving file in internal storage android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13161470/saving-file-in-internal-storage-android)

[Delete internal storage file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3554722/how-to-delete-internal-storage-file-in-android)

Hope these will help you.

Comment: thank you, this are very helpful, but my need are more complex, please could you give a look a this question as well? THANKS!!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18375786/android-how-do-i-intercept-when-the-user-downloads-a-file-from-the-browser-or

Comment: You are welcome. I gave some sample codes on that question too please take a look at them