# Android: how do I intercept when the user downloads a file (from the browser or from the email or form other source)

Tags: android, file-upload, download

As posted in a previous question, that possibly is pointing me in the right direction,

I need to intercept the event of the user downloading a file (from the browser, form the email..) so that I can propmpt the user and save the file in a folder defined in my app.

And, viceversa I need to be able to intercept the event of the user uploading a file into a webpage, so that I can offer him to select the file from the folder defined in my app.

If somebody could point me in the right direction I would really be grateful!

If there is any open source solution already available that would be very useful as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this link: [Intercepting links from the browser to open my Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609573/intercepting-links-from-the-browser-to-open-my-android-app)

You can intercept the link like explained in the answer. Once you've got the link, it is up to you how to handle it through code. If you want to download it with your own applications to a folder you desire, you can use following codes:

[Download a File In Android From Remote Server](http://wininterview.blogspot.in/2013/04/download-file-in-android-from-remote.html)

[How to download file/image from url to your device](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-download-fileimage-url-your-device)

I hope these will help you.