# Save file internal storage android works just with the terminal

Tags: android, internal-storage

I am trying to save a file into internal storage.
I have seen these link:
[How To Read/Write String From A File In Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376807/how-to-read-write-string-from-a-file-in-android)
[saving file in internal storage android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13161470/saving-file-in-internal-storage-android)

They both work but just when i run my app with the terminal! i run the DDMS and i see the file saved.
But when i try with the galaxy nexus or lg optimus 2 the file is not saved.

thanks

Comment: You have to thank Samsung and LG for that. Not us.

Comment: I am gonna try to save into external storage instead

Answer (score 0):

In order to see your file saved into the internal storage you have to root your phone.