# Android Downloaded HTML content should not coping using file managers / through the USB connection

Tags: android, mobile, protected, android-assets, protected-mode

I'm developing a android application which is downloading contents from a API as a zip file and extract it in to the assets folder in the app.Then using the web view in the app can load that content.

How can i prevent user from directly access the extracted folders (using file manager) and only allow user to access the folders via the application?

Comment: Use internal private storage?..

Comment: thanks @shkschneider , I ll try that.

Comment: i used   String FILENAME = "iML_file";
            FileOutputStream fos = getApplicationContext().openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            but still couldn't add html files to created folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer from the below mentioned blogs .

to save my html files -
[saving file in internal storage android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13161470/saving-file-in-internal-storage-android)

And to load-
http://fixabc.xyz/question/14624567/load-somefile-html-file-from-internal-storage-to-a-webview-of-an-app

Thank you Stackoverflow!!!